# Facebook user status without access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know I can make a html get request to access a user's basic info. (for example: https://graph.facebook.com/facebook ). However, this does not show the user's statuses, even if they are public. If I access http://www.facebook.com/facebook without being logged into an account I am able to see this user's statuses. Is there a way to get these using the Graph API? Or any other way without having to log in or use an access token? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: that is not a user, that is a page. For reading the page wall, you ALWAYS need an access token.

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

"any valid access_token or user access_token". so, an app access token is good enough, no login required but you definitely need an app. Here´s how to get an app access token:

```
$app_access_token = APP_ID . '|' . APP_SECRET;
```

Comment: to get the access token, don't i have the give permissions to the application first? this requiring to be logged in?

Comment: no, the app access token is different, i added it to the answer.